# How to seed a Rails 3.1 app with scoped mass assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mass-assignment, scoped-mass-assignment

How does Rails 3.1 (RC4) and scoped mass assignment expect us to work with seeds.rb when loading a list of data.

For example. I normally have something like:

```
City.create([
  { :name => 'Chicago' }, 
  { :name => 'Copenhagen' }, 
  ...
])
```

Which creates over 100+ cities. this doesn't work anymore since the City model has a scoped mass assignment `:as => :admin`.

As far as I know, the `.create()` method does not allow us to throw in `:as => :admin`.
Only `.new()` and `.update_attributes()` allows us to do this with `:as => :admin`.

So doing something like (below) is cumbersome (especially for 100+ records):

```
city1 = City.new({ :name => 'Chicago' }, :as => :admin)
city1.save
city2 = City.new({ :name => 'Copenhagen' }, :as => :admin)
city2.save
```

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
City.create([
  { :name => 'Chicago' }, 
  { :name => 'Copenhagen' }, 
  ...
], :without_protection => true)
```

This completely overrides the mass assignment protection - so be sure to only use this in say the seeds.